# Create a cloud scheduler job in CLI with nested json request body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler, google-workflows

I am running into trouble trying to schedule a Workflow using Google Cloud Scheduler through the Google CLI.

In particular my workflow requires the following request body:

```json
{
"arg1": "some_string",
"arg2": "some_other_string",
"arg3": [
    {
      "foo": "foo1",
      "bar": "bar1"
    },
    {
      "foo": "foo2",
      "bar": "bar2"
    }
  ]
}
```

In a different workflow with request body consisting only of `arg1` and `arg2` I was able to schedule a cloud function using the double-escaped json string format:

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http <NAME> --schedule=<CRON> --uri=<URI> --message-body="{\"argument\": \"{\\\"arg1\\\":\\\"some_string\\\",\\\"arg2\\\":\\\"some_other_string\\\"}\"}" --time-zone="UTC"
```

With the above request body I am unclear how to do this, I tried setting the message-body as

```
"{\"argument\": \"{\\\"arg1\\\":\\\"some_string\\\",\\\"arg2\\\":\\\"some_other_string\\\",\\\"arg3\\\":\\\"[{\\\\\"foo\\\\\":\\\\\"foo1\\\\\",\\\\\"bar\\\\\":\\\\\"bar1\\\\\"}]\\\"}\"}"
```

But it didn't seem to like this and threw an "INVALID ARGUMENT" status. I've also tried a few other variations such as without quotes around the list brackets but haven't had any success.

Apologies for how ugly these strings are. Is anyone aware how to format them correctly, or better yet, a simplified way of entering the request body in the command?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** I have tried using the `--message-body-from-file` argument as mentioned in the comments by @john-hanley. I found it still required escape quotes to work on my simple case.

**body.json**

```
{"argument": "{\"arg1\":\"some_string\",\"arg2\":\"some_other_string\"}"}
```

When I tried the nested case however with no quotes around the list it did work!
**body.json**

```
{"argument": "{\"arg1\":\"some_string\",\"arg2\":\"some_other_string\", \"arg3\": [{\"foo\": \"foo1\", \"bar\": \"bar1\"},{\"foo\":\"foo2\", \"bar\": \"bar2\"}]"}
```

Comment: I recommend using the command argument `--message-body-from-file` so that you do not need to mangle (escape) the JSON. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--message-body-from-file

Comment: Use that method and update your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated my question. It still seems to require an escaped json.

Comment: Your **body.json** is not JSON. That is escaped strings. Remove the `\`` characters and the `"` before `{` and  after `}`. Example `{"argument": {"arg1": "some_string" ... }}`

Comment: It didn't seem to work like that as the value for key "argument" seems to have to be a string. That being said, I resolved the issue with the complex case using the --message-body-from-file and not quoting the repeated field as above. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Why do do you have `{"argument":`? That does not match the JSON in the first part of you question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by incorporating comments by @JohnHanley and unquoting the repeated field

**Command:**

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http <NAME> --schedule=<CRON> --uri=<URI> --message-body-from-file="body.json" --time-zone="UTC"
```

**body.json**

```
{"argument": "{\"arg1\":\"some_string\",\"arg2\":\"some_other_string\", \"arg3\": [{\"foo\": \"foo1\", \"bar\": \"bar1\"},{\"foo\":\"foo2\", \"bar\": \"bar2\"}]"}
```